# Plot points of elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm interested in plotting points of an elliptic curve over the real numbers. I'm looking to plot a few curves, but one like y^2 = x^3 + 7 would be an example of one. This is simple enough when x is positive, but when it's negative, I'm unsure how to find values. Are there any well-known algorithms for doing this?

Comment: If you have, say $x=-2$, then your equation reads $y^2=-1$. That doesn't have any solutions. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: If you want points with real coordinates, it's simple enough to see when the right side is non negative, then for those $x$ a plus or minus squareroot gives the two $y values.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Arthur right, that's true. I think what I'm struggling to wrap my head around is finding points of interest that do have solutions. For instance, how far back should I go before I know that there are no solutions anymore?

Comment: You get a real point when $x^3+7\ge0$, that is iff $x\ge-\sqrt[3]7$.

Answer (score 0):

Just plot the positive and negative roots:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE! If you're familiar with programming, you can compute a list of points $(x,y)$ of the curve on your own. In view of the above curve, as Lord Shark said, real-valued points fulfill $x\geq -\sqrt[3]{7}$. Just loop over values $x$ and compute the $y$-values. Its easy with a computer algebra system like Maple.